# Unable to install ReactNative app on IOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I am working on a ReactNative app on MAC. To setup a simulator, I have created a sample project in XCode and have installed a simulator from Preferences -> Components. Now when I run my ReactNative project using "react-native run-ios",
the simulator launches but then I receive the error:

```
    error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" 
    command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build 
    logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening MyNewProject.xcodeproj.
```

At the end of the terminal, there is another error:

```
'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
```

The simulator does launch, but my app does not get installed on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: react-native version and Xcode version ??

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1, 
react-native: 0.60.4,
Xcode version: 9.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this was a compatibility issue of Xcode 9.4.1 with React Native 0.60.4. The issue was resolved by downgrading the **React Native version to 0.59.9**

Answer (score 0):

More than often, error code 65 can be fix by closing your bundler, deleting node_modules and installing packages again. Try:

CLOSE BUNDLER WINDOW

`rm -rf node_modules`
`npm install` <- yarn should work too but do npm to be safe
`react-native run-ios`

also not a bad idea to remove all .lock files to avoid conflict between yarn and npm

sometimes reac-native gets ahead of the bundler so if you don't see the app on the emulator, run
`react-native run-ios`
one more time

Comment: Does not work. And the issue is not that i cant see the app on simulator, obviously if there are errors then app would not get installed on the simulator @Luis Suarez